# Set custom attribute on Enum value in referenced DLL

Tags: c#

We can set custom attributes on types in a referenced DLL in the following way:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class AttributeForExternType : Attribute
{
    public ExternTypeAttribute(Type type)
    {
        ExternType = type;
    }
    public Type ExternType { get; }
}

// set in assembly info:
[assembly: ExternTypeAttribute(typeof(Extern.Type))]
```

And custom attributes set on enums and fields in our projects:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Enum)]
public sealed class InternEnumAttribute : Attribute { }

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public sealed class InternFieldAttribute: Attribute { }

enum MyEnum
{
    FieldA,
    [InternFieldAttribute]
    FieldB
}
```

**Question:** Is it able to define and use custom attributes on referenced enum values?

Comment: *We can set custom attributes on types* Are you sure of this?

Comment: @xanatos Yes, I'm sure...

Comment: By referenced you mean other 3rd party DLL?

Comment: Your AttributeForExternType does not set any attributes on any external types. It sets attribute on your assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add attributes to preexisting types. You can only add attributes if you can modify the source code...

```
// set in assembly info:
[assembly: ExternTypeAttribute(typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<int>))]
[assembly: ExternTypeAttribute(typeof(System.Attribute))]
[assembly: ExternTypeAttribute(typeof(System.Console))]
[assembly: ExternTypeAttribute(typeof(System.DateTime))]

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class ExternTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ExternTypeAttribute(Type type)
    {
        ExternType = type;
    }
    public Type ExternType { get; }
}

var attrs1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes<ExternTypeAttribute>().ToArray();
var attrs2 = typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<int>).GetCustomAttributes<ExternTypeAttribute>().ToArray();
var attrs3 = typeof(System.Attribute).GetCustomAttributes<ExternTypeAttribute>().ToArray();
var attrs4 = typeof(System.Console).GetCustomAttributes<ExternTypeAttribute>().ToArray();
var attrs5 = typeof(System.DateTime).GetCustomAttributes<ExternTypeAttribute>().ToArray();

Console.WriteLine("This assembly: {0}, attached to types: {1} {2} {3} {4}", attrs1.Length, attrs2.Length, attrs3.Length, attrs4.Length, attrs5.Length);
```

The result is:

> This assembly: 4, attached to types: 0, 0, 0, 0

Note that there is the [Type Descriptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171819.aspx) subsystem, but it is specialized and used primarily for designers.